# How to return multiple arguments from AJAX callback function

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, callbacks

First of all, please don't mark the question as duplicate as I didn't ask how to send arguments with ajax request.

I want to receive some extra arguments on ajax success. My callback function will return some html data. But I want to get some other arguments with that data.

maybe something like:

```
        success: function( data, arg_1, arg_2 ) {
            if( arg_1 ) {
                $('selector').append( data );
            } else if( arg_2  ) {
                $('other_selector').append( data );
            }
        }
```

But I don't know how to pass arguments like this. Any idea?

My current callback function makes a query with custom post and uses `get_template_part()` function to load them.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried returning an array instead?

```
wp_send_json($an_array_of_your_vals);
```

And then parse the array in the success function?

```
success: function( data ) {
   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

   if( obj.arg_1 ) {
            $('selector').append( obj.content );
   } else if( obj.arg_2  ) {
            $('other_selector').append( obj.content );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thx toscho for the edit.

Comment: That won't not work for me. In my question, I mentioned that, my callback function uses `get_template_part()` function. It uses to echo out my result automatically So, I cannot pass them into `wp_send_json()` function.

Comment: @SohanZaman You can put the output per [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) into a string.